# Accordion inside bootstrap select

Tags: accordion, bootstrap-select

I am trying to implement accordion inside a select box. TO show the select box I am using silvio moreto bootstrap select. The dropdown is a multi select dropdown with optgroups. It was working pretty fine but since there are a lot of elements in the dropdown there is a new requirement of showing the values in a collapsible format.

I think accordion should be a good fit for me but I am unable to find out how to implement it with bootstrap select.

This is the code I use for my select box

```
<select id="influencerNameCombo" title='Choose Influencer' data-live-search="true" data-actions-box="true" name="valueCombo[]" class="select_dropdown_style show-menu-arrow" data-width="100%" multiple data-selected-text-format="count>3" >

                        <optgroup class="cateGory1" label="cateGory1">
                            <option value="85" selected="selected" class="">Wohnidee MagazinÂ&nbsp;Â&nbsp;Â&nbsp;Â&nbsp;Â&nbsp;Â&nbsp;Â&nbsp;Â&nbsp;</option>
                            <option value="x" selected="selected" class="">Some Value1</option>
                            <option value="y" selected="selected" class="">Some Value2</option>
                            <option value="z" selected="selected" class="">Some Value3</option>
                            <option value="a" selected="selected" class="">Some Value4</option>
                            <option value="b" selected="selected" class="">Some Value5</option>
                            <option value="c" selected="selected" class="">Some Value6</option>
                        </optgroup>

                        <optgroup class="cateGory2" label="cateGory2">

                                <option value="qw" selected="selected" class="">Some Value7</option>

                        </optgroup>

                        <optgroup class="cateGory3" label="cateGory3">

                                <option value="qw2" selected="selected" class="">Some Value10</option>

                        </optgroup>

                </select>
```

After populating the dropdown I call

```
$('select').selectpicker();
```

Any suggestion/solution/path forward is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add some of your code

Comment: @lifeisfoo - Added the code. Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

After spending some time with silvio moreto's bootstrap-select I was able to fix this issue. 
I have made some enhancements to the js and it is working fine.

Below is the link 
https://jsfiddle.net/zqvvuts6/5/

```
<select id="filter_sport" multiple="multiple"  name="filter_sport" 
                class="selectpicker" title='Choose a Sport'  data-actions-box="true" class="show-menu-arrow" 
                data-selected-text-format="count>3" 
                data-single-item-selected = "Sport Selected"
                data-all-items-selected="All Sports" 
                ata-multi-item-selected = "Sports Selected">


                    <option value="11" selected="selected">Cricket</option>
                    <option value="15" selected="selected">Football</option>
                    <option value="3" selected="selected">Hockey</option>
                    <option value="16" selected="selected">MMA</option>
                    <option value="6" selected="selected">Others</option>
</select>


<select class="show-menu-arrow" multiple data-actions-box="true" data-selected-text-format="count>2" >
 <optgroup label="Swedish Cars" data-collapsible-optgroup= "true" data-load-       collapse-optgroup ="true">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="German Cars" data-collapsible-optgroup= "true" data-load-collapse-optgroup ="false">
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
```

Above snippet contains how html needs to be changed to configure it and we can see there are two attributes

```
data-collapsible-optgroup= "true" data-load-collapse-optgroup ="false"
```

Here data-collapsible-optgroup determines if that particular optgroup is collapsed or not. If it is enabled, then the second option determines if it s collapsed at the page load time or not.

It also has few extra small features which may come in handy if someone wants to use them like displaying custom text rather than the boring "items selected" text. 
So if you have selected 5 toys you will be able to see 5 toys rather than 5 items.

Please check and let me know about the fix and if this can be improved any further.

Happy Learning :)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Could you please advice is it possible to change a shape of a rectangle to make it look left rather that down when the group is collapsed. Also is it possible to draw a chackbox near to the group name and make it checked when all items are selected and unchecked on the other case? Thank You

Comment: Hey Jack.. definitely doable but you may need to look into little bit into that.. I am bit stuck these days